# Evaluate method to get result for notes web view

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I am using `evaluate` function in lotusscript to get a value of certain expression.

The formula is working fine when kept in the column of a view, but as soon as it is passed in evaluate, it is throwing error as "Error in evaluate macro", might be I am using wrong suntax.

```
Set Eval= Evaluate({@Text(@If(@Member(@Subset(txtRejectedApprovers;-1);txtApprover1:txtApprover2:txtApprover3:txtApprover4)-@Member(@Name([CN];txtApprovedApprovers[n]);txtApprover1:txtApprover2:txtApprover3:txtApprover4)>0;"1";"0")))},foundDoc)
```

`txtApprover1` and other fields are coming from `foundDoc` document.

Answer (score 1):

First thing. You shouldn't use such complex evaluate statement because if there are errors or unexpected results its very difficult to find the reason.

I think your error is one bracket to much at the end of your statement. Here is the code which doesn't return the error:

```
Set Eval= Evaluate({@Text(@If(@Member(@Subset(txtRejectedApprovers;-1);txtApprover1:txtApprover2:txtApprover3:txtApprover4)-@Member(@Name([CN];txtApprovedApprovers[n]);txtApprover1:txtApprover2:txtApprover3:txtApprover4)>0;"1";"0"))},foundDoc)
```

Comment: Upvoted, but I disagree with the "First thing."  A complex evaluate statement is perfectly okay. In fact, it's particularly useful to avoid writing new complex logic in native LotusScript when you have already debugged the formula in Domino Designer. You just have to transcribe the formula properly, and it's pretty easy to check that by copying the formula from code (or from the debugger if you the formula is built in code) into a text editor, and then copying a working model formula from Domino Designer onto the next text line and just compare them.